# Issue getting csv data into mysql table with python and mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-python

I've been fighting with this python code for a while and getting various errors when I try to execute.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
# open the connection to the MySQL server.
# using MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='myhostinfo',
user='me',
passwd='mypw',
db='thedatabase')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
# read the presidents.csv file using the python
# csv module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
csv_data = csv.reader(file('CHN-mod.csv'))
# execute the for clicle and insert the csv into the
# database.
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO INDICATORS(INDICATORNAME, \
            , INDICATORCODE)' \
            'VALUES(%s, %s)',  row)
#close the connection to the database.
cursor.close()
print "Import to MySQL is over"
```

My code validates in an online python validator, but I'm getting errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importdata.py", line 23, in <module>
    'VALUES(%s, %s)' , row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaultterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' INDICATORCODE)VALUES('Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code'>' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: 'INSERT INTO INDICATORS(INDICATORNAME, \
            , INDICATORCODE)' \
            'VALUES(%s, %s)'
Out[1]: 'INSERT INTO INDICATORS(INDICATORNAME,             , INDICATORCODE)VALUES(%s, %s)'
```

There are two commas after `INDICATORNAME`.

---

Use a multiline string instead:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO INDICATORS (INDICATORNAME, INDICATORCODE)
                  VALUES (%s, %s)''', row)
```

It is much easier to read and will avoid the problem you ran into. 
MySQLdb parses the string (despite the whitespaces) just fine.

---

To insert parts of each row to three different tables, you could do something like this:

```
insert_indicators = '''INSERT INTO INDICATORS (INDICATORNAME, INDICATORCODE)
                       VALUES (%s, %s)'''
insert_foo = 'INSERT INTO FOO (...) VALUES (%s)' % (','.join(['%s']*10))
insert_bar = 'INSERT INTO BAR (...) VALUES (%s)' % (','.join(['%s']*10))

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute(insert_indicators, row[:2])
    cursor.execute(insert_foo, row[2:12])
    cursor.execute(insert_bar, row[12:22])
```

Comment: I have a csv file with many columns and I want to import two to one table, ten to another, and ten to another still. How could I modify the code to be selective like that?